# Product of Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers, almost-everywhere

I know that there exists some discussions related to my question, however, I couldn't find an explanation for my question. I hope it is not a duplicate.

> Let $X_n$ be sequence of i.i.d. uniform distributions on $(0,a)$, and define $Y_n = \prod^n_k X_k$. 
>   **Problem**
>   For what values of $a$, $\lim Y_n\to 0$ a.s.

**Attempt**
Note that,
\begin{equation}
Y_n = \exp\left(n\times\frac{1}{n}\sum_k^n \log(X_k)\right)
\end{equation}
and by SLLN, if $E\log(X_1)<0$ it follows that $Y_n\to 0$ a.s., which is true if $a<e$.

**Question** How can I discuss $a=e$?

Comment: If $a=e$, then $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log X_k$ defines a random walk on the real line with centered integrable steps, hence $(S_n)$ is recurrent, which implies that $(Y_n)$ is almost surely unbounded. In particular, $P(Y_n\to0)=0$.

Comment: Many thanks, I will accept if you copy it as answer.

Comment: @Jo' It's been a while so I think you should copy, post it yourself, and accept it. Self-answering is encouraged as long as the content is solid, and here especially it is better than leaving the post unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment of Did,

If $a=e$, then $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log X_k$ defines a random walk on the real line with centered integrable steps,
 hence $(S_n)$ is recurrent, which implies that $(Y_n)$ is almost surely unbounded.
 In particular, $P(Y_n \to 0) = 0$.